# Using aliases in a heredoc that ssh a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, heredoc

I have a function in my ~/.bashrc that is defined as follow

```
function sshpushg() {
    iro <<EOF      #iro is sshpass -p *** ssh addressOfServer
    ssh computer01 #connect to my remote computer
    Work           
    st
    add
    git commit -m "pushing automatically by ssh"
    pushg
    EOF
}
```

And in my remote account my ~/.bashrc file has the following lines

```
alias Work=' cd ~/Documents/Work'
alias st='git status'
alias add='git add -A'
alias pushg='git push origin master'
```

I want the function sshpushg to automatically add, commit and push everything in my Work folder to github, but when I run the command I have the errors:

```
-bash: line 1: Work: command not found
-bash: line 2: st:  command not found
-bash: line 3: add: command not found
```

And then a bunch of errors that say that this is not a git repository since Work wasn't executed and I am not in the right directory.

How do I use the aliases set up on my remote account in my function sshpushg? Obviously, I could just retype all the command without the aliases but is there a way to not do so?

Comment: Why are you connecting to `addressOfServer` and then to `computer01`?

Comment: @che because adressOfServer is to be used as a connect point to the other computers since it does not have a lot of memory / CPU. But yes in practice I could just run directly on addressOfServer, but it is just accepted in my lab that we should not used addressOfServer to do anything else than connect to our computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run ssh with input script, it does not create a terminal and its shell does not run `~/.bashrc`. You might be able to get around this by forcing an interactive shell with `ssh computer01 bash -i`, but that will try to use the input file as terminal and give you another set of errors:

```
$ ssh my-server bash -i <<< 'aliastest'
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
che@my-server ~ $ aliastest
alias works
che@my-server ~ $ exit
```

You could probably get around this by faking a terminal somehow, but the easiest way would be to either write the commands out, or by creating a script on the server and then running it, along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/Work
git status
git add -A
git push origin master
```

and then running it by

```
sshpass -p *** ssh addressOfServer ssh computer01 ~/path/to/my/script.sh
```